# To detect shapes in a irregular image

Tags: python, opencv, contour

Trying to find the circles and rectangle (or square) in an irregular object    using contours,edge detection but not getting the output properly.

1. I tried changing values of canny values and epsilon(contour approx) but was not able to detect,
2. Another difficulty iam facing is lot hand written character are there in the metal object so my code is detecting that also as a shape

Can anyone please help me on detecting this required shape on this object using opencv-python.

Metal object
[image]

```
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('part1.jpg')

#image = cv2.imread('C:\Python27\plates\plates2.1.jpg')#$episolon==0.04,len=5,6
#image = cv2.imread('C:\Python27\plates\plates4.jpg')
#image = cv2.imread('C:\Python27\plates\plates1.jpg')
#image = cv2.imread('C:\Python27\plates\plates3.jpg')#episilon=0.0370,len=5
#image = cv2.imread('C:\Python27\plates\plates5.jpg') #change the episilon to 0.01
#image = cv2.imread('C:\Python27\plates\plates6.jpg')#not working properly


cv2.namedWindow('Image')




#for angle in xrange(0, 360, 90):
# rotate the image and display it
#image = imutils.rotate(image, angle=angle)


#gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)


#edges=cv2.Canny(image,200,650)#plates3.jpg,plates1.jpg,plates5.jpg,
#edges=cv2.Canny(image,200,500)#plates4.jpg
#edges=cv2.Canny(image,200,589)#plates2.1.jpg
#edges=cv2.Canny(image,100,450)
edges=cv2.Canny(image,300,589)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)


#thresh = cv2.erode(edges,kernel,iterations = 1)
#thresh = cv2.dilate(edges,kernel,iterations = 1)
#thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
sd = ShapeDetector()
print len(cnts)
for c in cnts:

        shape = "unidentified"
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.0373* peri, True)





        if len(approx) == 4:

            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
            #ar = w / float(h)


            #shape = "slots" if ar >= 0.95 and ar <= 1.05 else "slots"
            shape="slots"
            #cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
            box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
            box = np.int0(box)
            cv2.drawContours(image,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
            #cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.putText(image, shape, (int(x), int(y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5, (255, 255, 255), 4)

        elif len(approx)==2:
            shape="nothing"

            (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
            center = (int(x),int(y))
            radius = int(radius)
            #cv2.circle(image,center,radius,(0,255,0),2)
            #cv2.putText(image, shape, (int(x), int(y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5, (255, 255, 255), 4)

        elif len(approx)==5:
            shape="nothing"
        elif len(approx)==3:
            shape="nothing"

        elif len(approx)==6:
            shape="nothing"





        else:
            shape = "c"+str(len(approx))
            (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
            center = (int(x),int(y))
            radius = int(radius)
            cv2.circle(image,center,radius,(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.putText(image, shape, (int(x), int(y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)


cv2.imshow("Image",image)
cv2.imshow("edges", thresh)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Do you have to find number of holes in this case only or for many images?

Comment: @GarvitaTiwariyes for many images.

Comment: and do all images have this same metal object? If yes you can do colour based segmentation of this metal object only( or segmentation using template matching)  and then you can find holes in the segmented image using adaptive binarization . It should give correct output in majority of cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use binarization. You will get blobs that you can discriminate by size, location and other geometric criteria.

[image]

Comment: Always amazing to see how users of OpenCV rush to edge detection when they want to extract shapes. In 99% of the cases, Canny is unusable, while simple or adaptive binarization does marvels.

Comment: @vigneshs No, I didn't use OpenCV. But this is a trivial binarization, one line of code. Spend a minimum of effort.